# What needs to be set up for Hyperledger Composer events to work?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I did the following:

1. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html
2. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/applications/subscribing-to-events.html

The docs make it seem like this is all you need to stick in your Node.js server:

```
businessNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
    // event: { "$class": "org.namespace.BasicEvent", "eventId": "0000-0000-0000-000000#0" }
    console.log(event);
});
```

But nothing is happening in my case. I can see my transactions emitting events through the playground UI, but they aren't hitting my Node.js server.

Do I have to set up my own websocket server or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

1. Emit your events in your TP code (and you've done this) - example -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js#L28 or as shown at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/business-network/publishing-events.html
2. Have defined the Event class in your model file - eg -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/models/trading.cto#L25 - then updated to the runtime business network that you previously deployed using `composer network update`
3. The eventId property in `event` is always the same as the transactionId of the transaction which emitted the event.

Comment: Thank you! They key step I was missing was `composer network update`. My network didn't start with events; I added them in later, and didn't know I had to run that command.